# reactjs-popup popup menu doesn't close after clicking an option

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-popup

I am trying to implement a popup menu which closes after a button or a link is clicked with reactjs-popup library.

The documentation uses { close => (...content) } for modal but this approach doesn't work for popup menu.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.